# javascript for scrollTo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        $('a.link').click(function () {  
            $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 400);
            $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            return false;  
        });  
    });
    function setPosition(check, div, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) {
    if(check==='#box1')
        {
            $(div).scrollTo(p1, 400);
        }
    else if(check==='#box2')
        {
            $(div).scrollTo(p2, 400);
        }
    else if(check==='#box3')
        {
            $(div).scrollTo(p3, 400);
        }
    else if(check==='#box4')
        {
            $(div).scrollTo(p4, 400);
        }
    else
        {
            $(div).scrollTo(p5, 400);
        }
    };
```

but for box4and box 5, thats won't slide to left . that slide to bottom of box1 . 
so the layout be like this :

```
_____________________________________________________________________
|              |                 |                 |                |
|              |                 |                 |                |
|     box1     |      box2       |       box3      |      box4      |
|              |                 |                 |                | 
|______________|_________________|_________________|________________|
|              |                 |                 |                |
|              |                 |                 |                |
|    box5      |      box6       |      box7       |      box8      |
|              |                 |                 |                |
|______________|_________________|_________________|________________|
```

I wont the page all stright to right not go down .
anysugest ? how can I change it ?
thank you very much for all advice or suggest.

Comment: Try to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/6cmjz/ (notice the scrollbar on the bottom)

Simply set a width to your wrapper.

```
#wrapper{
   width: 1000px;
}
```